# MATLAB ind2sub is not the inverse of sub2ind

Tags: matlab

I implemented an image processing algorithm what needs to sweep the image with a line. I generate the valid points of the line into two vectors: `lx_valid`, and `ly_valid`. Then I generate the linear indices with `sub2ind`, and plot the results. As you can see, my line clearly intersects the object, but `locmax == 0` after running the code. The coordinates are all valid (inside the image); but I've got one even stranger result: if I generate the coordinates as `ind2sub(size(Im), c)` I don't even get back my coordinates. I'm sure it's something small, but I can't get it.

```
valid = lx >= 1 & size(Im, 2) >= lx & ly >= 1 & size(Im, 1) >= ly;
lx_valid = lx(valid);
ly_valid = ly(valid);
c = sub2ind(size(Im), ly_valid, lx_valid);
locmax = max(Im(c));
imshow(Im);plot(lx_valid,ly_valid,'go');
```

[image: imshow(Im);plot(lx_valid,ly_valid,'go'); works as expected]

Comment: Can you print size(Im) ? (Just in case it is 3d)

Comment: Interesting. I generated some synthetic data and it works fine for me. Maybe you add `Im` generation to the code? Maybe `Im` is 3D, as Oli suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem: the indices that were generated by sub2ind were staturated, and were returned as uint16 silently. If I convert the parameters to double, sub2ind returns a double value which is big enough for the indices.

```
valid = lx >= 1 & size(Im, 2) >= lx & ly >= 1 & size(Im, 1) >= ly; 
lx_valid = double(lx(valid)); 
ly_valid = double(ly(valid)); 
c = sub2ind(size(Im), ly_valid, lx_valid); 
locmax = max(Im(c)); 
imshow(Im);plot(lx_valid,ly_valid,'go');
```